# What is this plant with bright red and black seeds?

Tags: identification

[image]

I don't know what I found.  Please help me figure out what I found and also they were pretty so I made a few necklaces

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Abrus precatorius

These grow on a vine which can become invasive in tropical areas. Flowers on the vine are fairly small, violet in color and relatively inconspicuous, their real attraction is the bright red seeds that form in pods in the winter.

This vine is cold hardy in zone 9b and warmer. From my experience, it is NOT suitable to grow as an annual in colder zones as it does not bloom the first year from seed.

**Abrus precatorius seeds are very poisonous! **
Found info on

http://www.onalee.com/store.php/onaleeisrael/pd9091944/rosaryprayer_bead_redblacksailors_valentine_crabs_eye_abrus_precatorius

Comment: Those are  very cool. My first search for ladybug plant failed lol. Looks look you did exactly what lot of people use them for. Thanks for posting, was a interesting plant to find out about.